# Lightning Gantt Chart

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am new to lightning experience and got stuck in a requirement.

Here are the details.

I want to display data in Gantt Chart where X-Axis shows the Name and Y-Axis contains the range of 2 date field(i.e due date and completed date).
Data(Record Name) is displaying perfect on the Y-axis and not able to pass complete date on the x-axis.

Below are the code.

```
<aura:component controller="GraphController" 
     implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,
     flexipage:availableForRecordHome,
     force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.Chart}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.ctr}"/>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-1 
         slds-small-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--3-of-4"> 
        <canvas aura:id="lineChart" id="lineChart"/> 
    </div> 
</aura:component>
```

### Controller Class

```
public static string getLineChartMap(){
        List<Work_Tasks__c> myLineChartVarList = new List<Work_Tasks__c>();
        myLineChartVarList =[SELECT  Name, Date_Completed__c, Due_Date__c FROM Work_Tasks__c];
        System.debug('myLineChartVarList'+myLineChartVarList);       
        return JSON.Serialize(myLineChartVarList);
    }
```

### Controller.js

```
({  
    ctr : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var temp = [];
        var temp2 = [];
        var action1 = cmp.get("c.getLineChartMap");
        var action = cmp.get("c.getChartMap");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            if(response.getState() === 'SUCCESS' && response.getReturnValue()){
                temp = response.getReturnValue();
                helper.createGraph(cmp, temp);
            }
        });      
        action1.setCallback(this, function(response){                       
            if(response.getState() === 'SUCCESS' && response.getReturnValue()){
                temp2 = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
                helper.createLineGraph(cmp, temp2);
            }            
        });  
       $A.enqueueAction(action);    
       $A.enqueueAction(action1);
    }
})
```

### Helper class

```
createLineGraph : function(cmp, temp) {

        var label = [];
        var firstValue = [];
        var secondValue = [];

        for(var a=0; a< temp.length; a++){
            console.debug(temp[a]["label"]);
            label.push(temp[a]["label"]);
            firstValue.push(temp[a]["firstValue"]);
            secondValue.push(temp[a]["secondValue"]);                     
        }    
        var el = cmp.find('lineChart').getElement();
        var ctx = el.getContext('2d');

        new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                    labels: label,
                    datasets: [{
                      label: 'Due Date',
                      data: firstValue,
                      backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.4)"
                    }, {
                      label: 'Completed Date',
                      data: secondValue,
                      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
                    }]
                  }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Hi Aishwary, Welcome to SF.SE. I'd suggest you show us your page component code and also tell us what's working and what isn't, along with what you've done to try and troubleshoot your problem. If you do that, I it's more likely that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful.

Comment: @crmprogdev,

Thanks for your response. Below is the Component Code:

Component Code :

<aura:component controller="GraphController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
 <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.Chart}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.ctr}"/>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-1 slds-small-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--3-of-4">
     <canvas aura:id="lineChart" id="lineChart"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>

Desired Output: Gantt Chart
X-axis: Date Span
Y-axis: Name

Comment: You can edit your original post at any time by clicking on the [edit link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/247896/edit) at the bottom left of your post. Please do not ask people to try to understand your code when it's posted from a comment. It's nearly impossible for most of us to decipher. Thank you.